# How to get the schema of a postgresql jsonb field

Tags: postgresql

I recognize that jsonb is unstructured data, and therefore does not have a fixed schema. However, with some unstructured stores such as elasticsearch, it is possible to get the aggregate schema of all data in an index.

Is there a way to do this with PostgreSQL? If not native to Postgres, is there a third-party tool that offers this functionality?

As an example, this is a mapping result from elasticsearch; From this I know that I have a "go" and "walk" field that are both text types. I know that not all entries will have those fields, but they may have those fields.

```
{
  "verbs" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        },
        "go" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "walk" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the result you expect? A list of all keys? You probably get better answers if you provide some sample data and the expected output based on that

Comment: @SteveJ I didn't get your point. schema only appliable to tables. jsonb is datatype. So only columns have data type..

Comment: @Mark; Thank you. I believe that your statement is only explicitly true. For example, I could read all of the data rows and, with much patience, eventually come up with an exhaustive list of all potential shapes (schemas) and assign the least generic data type to each. What value it has would be dependent on the consistency of the data, but it could be done.